# Laravel Eloquent How to Combine Many to Many and One to Many relationships with 3 table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a database like this.

```
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| a_b            |
| a_c            |
| as             |
| bs             |
| cs             |
+----------------+
```

bs and cs tables have many to many relationship with as table. So a_b table and a_c table are pivot tables.

This is as table

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | A1   |
|  2 | A2   |
+----+------+
```

This is bs table

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | B1   |
+----+------+
```

And this is cs table

```
+----+------+------+
| id | b_id | name |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |    1 | C1   |
|  2 |    1 | C2   |
+----+------+------+
```

this is a_b pivot table

```
+------+------+
| a_id | b_id |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
+------+------+
```

And this is a_c pivot table.

```
+------+------+
| a_id | c_id |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |
+------+------+
```

And this is my A model for the as table.

```
class A extends Model
{
    protected $table = "as";
    public function b(){
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\B");
    }
    public function c(){
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\C");
    }
}
```

And this is B model for bs table

```
class B extends Model
{
    protected $table = "bs";
    public function c(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\C");
    }
}
```

I just want to query C table values as related to A table.

I tried this query

```
A::where("id",1)->with("b.c")->get();
```

But this result also gives me C2 value which is related to A2 in "**as**" table. I want to get only C1 value which is related only A1 value in "**as**" table.

How can I do this ? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In your example data A1 relates to B1 which in turn relates to C2. And you are in fact nesting the `b.c` eager load, so you are loading Bs and Cs related to those Bs.

Have you tried `A::where("id",1)->with(["b", "c"])->get();`
?

Comment: Thank you for answer. But C model must be collected to B model with one to many relationship

Comment: I think there is no way to do it easily.